# C++ Multiplication for any base

Tags: c++, function, multiplication, radix

How can I modify this code to work for any base number? (binary, hex, base 10 etc)

```
int mult(int a, int b, int base){

    if((a<=base)||(b<=base)){ //only 1 digit
        return a*b;
    }
}
```

Comment: That already works for any "base". Integers don't have a particular "base" in themselves. Base only comes into it when you are converting to or from a printed representation.

Comment: Are you sure? if my base is base 4, and 'a' and 'b' are 3, it will print 9, which is not a number in base 4

Comment: That's right. The problem is not the *multiplication*, because the answer is still nine. The problem is when you're printing the result, you're printing (probably) in base 10. The question you need to ask is how to convert the result to a representation in base 4.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, thanks for the input

Comment: Are you looking is something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal(BCD) (binary-coded decimal)? It could be called decimal-coded something? In that case your example is not quite right because it doesn't handle carry correctly, for example in octal `3*3` should be `11` and **not** `9`.

Comment: I've not got the formatting of links in comments right yet. The link in my comment should be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal

Answer (score 1):

`int`, like all data types, are actually stored as binary. Normally, they're represented to you as hexadecimal if you are looking at memory (such as a debugger). Types like `int` and `float` are merely formatted into decimal by the various output systems.

As the data is binary itself, multiplication is already base-independent. It's the display of the product which is not. For example, say I had some 4-bit type:

`0010` (2) X `0100` (4) = `1000` (8)

This is exactly how C++ is already working - just with 32 or 64 bits instead of 4.

As such, there's no need for a function to multiply different bases differently. What you need is a function to display different bases. Luckily, C++ has several options for this. One is with STD's stream flags:

```
std::cout << std::oct << number << "\n";
```

There are, however, only 3 of these: [hexadecimal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/), [decimal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/dec/), and [octal](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/oct/). There are several [others](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags), but they deal with things other than base.

If you need other bases, I don't know of any libraries that provide such. I searched Boost but couldn't find that it did, but Boost is big and not so easy to search, so it might. There are some [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026468/optimizing-base-conversion-loop?rq=1) on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235371/fastest-base-conversion-method?rq=1) that you can look at for a broader usage.